# Use regex in R to replace blank with number

Tags: r, regex, data.table, stringr

Following `data.table`

```
df <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),
  variable=c("250","250.1","250.11","E70.9"))
df
id variable
1:  1      250
2:  2    250.1
3:  3   250.11
4:  4   E70.9
```

I want to add to the shorter strings `0` to fill up the decimals, but only if it starts with `250`. I did the following so far:

```
df <- set(df,which(df[,'variable']=="250"),'variable',value= '250.00')
df$variable <- str_replace_all(df$variable,"([2][5][0]\\.[:digit:][:space:])","([2][5][0]\\.[:digit:][0]))")
```

The first part is working and I can replace `250` with `250.00`. When I tried to use `stringsr` package and `regex`, it did not work out. Finally, I would like to have these results.

```
id variable
1:  1   250.00
2:  2   250.10
3:  3   250.11
4:  4   E70.9
```

What should I change to use `stringr` in the right way? Is there maybe a better solution in `data.table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` alternative:

```r
func <- function(x) {
  num <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
  ifelse(is.na(num), x, sprintf("%0.2f", num))
}
df <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4), variable=c("250","250.1","250.11","E70.9"))
df[grepl("^250", variable), variable := func(variable) ]
#    id variable
# 1:  1   250.00
# 2:  2   250.10
# 3:  3   250.11
# 4:  4    E70.9
```

This takes advantage of `sprintf` to do the heavy lifting of formatting numbers well.

One nice thing with this method is that if your *"250"* rule is because you didn't want to adjust the `"E70.9"` value, then it works just fine (since the "E" spoils `as.numeric`):

```r
df <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4), variable=c("250","250.1","250.11","E70.9"))
df[, variable := func(variable) ]
#    id variable
# 1:  1   250.00
# 2:  2   250.10
# 3:  3   250.11
# 4:  4    E70.9
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `sprintf`.  Create a logical condition with `case_when` by checking if the 'variable' starts with '250', then format those elements with `sprintf` or else return the 'variable'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(variable = case_when(str_detect(variable, '^250')
       ~ sprintf('%.2f', as.numeric(variable)), TRUE ~ variable))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
i1 <- grepl('^250', df$variable)
df$variable[i1] <- sprintf('%.2f', as.numeric(df$variable[i1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace` in the following way :

```
library(data.table)

df[, variable := stringr::str_replace(variable,'^250.*', function(m) 
                 sprintf('%.2f', as.numeric(m)))]
df
#   id variable
#1:  1   250.00
#2:  2   250.10
#3:  3   250.11
#4:  4    E70.9
```

`str_replace` only replaces those values that satisfy the `pattern` argument.